# For which $m$ does $x^n \equiv y^n \pmod{m}$ imply $x \equiv y \pmod{m}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How would I find, given an integer $n$, for which values of $m$ (also integer) does $x^n \equiv y^n \pmod{m}$ imply $x \equiv y \pmod{m}$?

Comment: No $m$ satisfies this condition. You probably mean $x\equiv y$ instead of $x=y$. Also, this question is not about abstract algebra.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry.

Comment: Suppose that $m$ happens to satisfy $\gcd(\phi(m),n)=1$. Does that allow you to prove the desired implication?